# ChromeDriverManager alternative for chromedriver 115+ in python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, seleniumbase

UPDATE: Using seleniumbase worked, per comment.

After the chromedriver updates with version 115, it's suggested to use the manager to handle the driver/executable installation like this:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

But I'm on VPN, which blocks this connection.
How do I manually specify the path to both the chromedriver and chrome testing executable?

And if anyone can link me to the documentation for this, I would be more than happy to read it, but I have not even been able to find it.

EDIT:
I tried this (I tried setting absolute paths and that didn't help):

```py
service = Service(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = 'chrome.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

and got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\p3000151\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\splunk_on_call-xABy5ETk-py3.8\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 49, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\p3000151\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\splunk_on_call-xABy5ETk-py3.8\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 54, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\p3000151\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\splunk_on_call-xABy5ETk-py3.8\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\p3000151\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\splunk_on_call-xABy5ETk-py3.8\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 291, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "C:\Users\p3000151\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\splunk_on_call-xABy5ETk-py3.8\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\p3000151\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\splunk_on_call-xABy5ETk-py3.8\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D0DD6F92+54962]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D0D44FF2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D0BFA6AB]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D0C2702A]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D0C24E5E]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D0C63A5B]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D0C634D0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D0C5B6E3]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D0C303E1]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D0C31624]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D1129782+3538594]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D117F520+3890240]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D11779DF+3858687]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D0E735B6+695510]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D0D50048]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D0D4C144]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D0D4C272]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D0D3C633]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFDC2167614+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFDC29426B1+33]
```

the log looks like this:

```
[1695134982.210][INFO]: Starting ChromeDriver 118.0.5993.3 (7a51b9ea23325fae1ec1dad5a02c67c2240d7b11-refs/branch-heads/5993@{#7}) on port 60693
[1695134982.210][INFO]: Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[1695134982.677][INFO]: [86d49340f523de943fea4c30087657ec] COMMAND InitSession {
   "capabilities": {
      "alwaysMatch": {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "args": [  ],
            "binary": "C:\\Users\\p3000151\\PycharmProjects\\SPLUNK ON CALL\\chrome.exe",
            "extensions": [  ]
         },
         "pageLoadStrategy": "normal"
      },
      "firstMatch": [ {
      } ]
   }
}
[1695134982.679][INFO]: Populating Preferences file: {
   "alternate_error_pages": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "autofill": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "browser": {
      "check_default_browser": false
   },
   "distribution": {
      "import_bookmarks": false,
      "import_history": false,
      "import_search_engine": false,
      "make_chrome_default_for_user": false,
      "skip_first_run_ui": true
   },
   "dns_prefetching": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "profile": {
      "content_settings": {
         "pattern_pairs": {
            "https://*,*": {
               "media-stream": {
                  "audio": "Default",
                  "video": "Default"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "default_content_setting_values": {
         "geolocation": 1
      },
      "default_content_settings": {
         "geolocation": 1,
         "mouselock": 1,
         "notifications": 1,
         "popups": 1,
         "ppapi-broker": 1
      },
      "password_manager_enabled": false
   },
   "safebrowsing": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "search": {
      "suggest_enabled": false
   },
   "translate": {
      "enabled": false
   }
}
[1695134982.680][INFO]: Populating Local State file: {
   "background_mode": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "ssl": {
      "rev_checking": {
         "enabled": false
      }
   }
}
[1695134982.686][INFO]: Launching chrome: "C:\Users\p3000151\PycharmProjects\SPLUNK ON CALL\chrome.exe" --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-background-networking --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --enable-automation --enable-logging --log-level=0 --no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=0 --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Users\p3000151\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4444_743592924" data:,
[1695134982.714][INFO]: [86d49340f523de943fea4c30087657ec] RESPONSE InitSession ERROR unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.
```

I'm using the win64 executables.
Could this have anything to do with my VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can specify the driver path and the browser binary location:

(The `.exe` is for Windows. If on Mac / Linux, it won't be there.)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "PATH_TO_BINARY.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

---

You might also be able to use the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) driver manager to get around the issue, which may avoid slowness that occurs when downloading drivers over a VPN.

(`pip install seleniumbase`, and run with `python`):

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome")
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I tried that and got the errors I've added to my post

Comment: Run as an administrator. The `Failed to create Chrome process` generally means there's a permissions issue.

Comment: I added an alternative driver manager (SeleniumBase) into my solution.

Comment: Using seleniumbase worked, thank you!